# Como codificar e decodificar strings base64 em C?

Tags: c, base64, encode

Preciso codificar (e decodificar) um `JSON` para ser transmitido da Web para um microcontrolador. O `JSON` que estou enviando é criptografado com o `AES 128`, mas o *cyphertext* contém caracteres não imprimíveis e obtive alguns problemas com isto. Por exemplo, quando tento receber estes dados no microcontrolador a decriptação não se dá de forma correta. Entretanto, se eu encripto e decripto uma string dentro do microcontrolador, o processo ocorre normalmente.

Acredito que o problema seja a codificação dos caracteres, pois existem caracteres não imprimíveis que não são transmitidos. Preciso então efetuar as seguintes etapas, exatamente nesta ordem:

1. Criptografar um texto utilizando o `AES 128`
2. **Codificar** o *cyphertext* em base64 para ser transmitido via Web
3. Receber os dados no microcontrolador
4. **Decodificar** o *cyphertext* em base64, para sua representação natural
5. Decriptografar o *cyphertext* usando o `AES 128`

Minha dúvida é: **como codificar e decodificar strings `base64` em `C`? Existe alguma biblioteca para isto?**

Edit: Existe alguma forma otimizada de fazer isto? Encontrei [um exemplo](http://ideone.com/HanXNA) que contem o algoritmo que decodifica, mas ele usa uma matriz enorme para fazer isto.

Comment: Se estás a usar OpenSSL para criptografar com AES 128, podes usá-lo também para [base64](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/crypto/BIO_f_base64.html).

Comment: glib tambem tem funçoes para base46 http://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.28/glib-Base64-Encoding.html

Answer (score 5):

Avelino, não julgue um código pelas suas matrizes!

O exemplo que você encontrou é baseado no arquivo `ap_base64.c` do projeto `APR - Apache Portable Runtime` ([veja aqui o código original](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/apr/apr-util/tags/PRE_APR_CHANGES/src/encoding/ap_base64.c)), que por sua vez, é bastante difundido e usado em diversos outros projetos. Ele foi implementado em C puro e não depende de nenhuma outra biblioteca externa.

Essa matriz enorme cheia de números mágicos que você mencionou é capaz de proporcionar um aumento considerável de performance no processamento de dados em `base64`, o que a torna bastante viável.

**Minha sugestão é:** Não tenha preconceito com esse código, ele é rápido, portável e bastante eficiente.

Segue (portanto) o código propriamente dito reescrito de forma a trabalhar somente com ASCII:

Header `base64.h`:

```
/*
    base64.h
*/

#ifndef __BASE64_H__
#define __BASE64_H__

int base64decode_len( const char * bufcoded );
int base64decode( char * bufplain, const char * bufcoded );

int base64encode_len( int len );
int base64encode( char * encoded, const char * string, int len );

#endif

/* fim-de-arquivo */
```

Implementação `base64.c`:

```
/*
    base64.c
*/

#include <string.h>

#include "base64.h"


static int base64decode_binary( unsigned char * bufplain, const char * bufcoded );
static int base64encode_binary( char * encoded, const unsigned char * string, int len );


static const char basis_64[] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/";

static const unsigned char pr2six[256] =
{
    64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64,
    64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64,
    64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 62, 64, 64, 64, 63,
    52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64,
    64,  0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14,
    15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64,
    64, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40,
    41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64,
    64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64,
    64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64,
    64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64,
    64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64,
    64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64,
    64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64,
    64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64,
    64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64
};


static int base64decode_binary( unsigned char * bufplain, const char * bufcoded )
{
    int nbytesdecoded;
    register const unsigned char *bufin;
    register unsigned char *bufout;
    register int nprbytes;

    bufin = (const unsigned char *) bufcoded;

    while (pr2six[*(bufin++)] <= 63);

    nprbytes = (bufin - (const unsigned char *) bufcoded) - 1;
    nbytesdecoded = ((nprbytes + 3) / 4) * 3;

    bufout = (unsigned char *) bufplain;
    bufin = (const unsigned char *) bufcoded;

    while (nprbytes > 4)
    {
        *(bufout++) = (unsigned char) (pr2six[*bufin] << 2 | pr2six[bufin[1]] >> 4);
        *(bufout++) = (unsigned char) (pr2six[bufin[1]] << 4 | pr2six[bufin[2]] >> 2);
        *(bufout++) = (unsigned char) (pr2six[bufin[2]] << 6 | pr2six[bufin[3]]);

        bufin += 4;
        nprbytes -= 4;
    }

    /* Note: (nprbytes == 1) would be an error, so just ingore that case */
    if (nprbytes > 1)
    {
        *(bufout++) = (unsigned char) (pr2six[*bufin] << 2 | pr2six[bufin[1]] >> 4);
    }

    if (nprbytes > 2)
    {
        *(bufout++) = (unsigned char) (pr2six[bufin[1]] << 4 | pr2six[bufin[2]] >> 2);
    }

    if (nprbytes > 3)
    {
        *(bufout++) = (unsigned char) (pr2six[bufin[2]] << 6 | pr2six[bufin[3]]);
    }

    *(bufout++) = '\0';
    nbytesdecoded -= (4 - nprbytes) & 3;

    return nbytesdecoded;
}


static int base64encode_binary(char *encoded, const unsigned char *string, int len )
{
    int i;
    char *p;

    p = encoded;

    for (i = 0; i < len - 2; i += 3)
    {
        *p++ = basis_64[(string[i] >> 2) & 0x3F];
        *p++ = basis_64[((string[i] & 0x3) << 4) | ((int) (string[i + 1] & 0xF0) >> 4)];
        *p++ = basis_64[((string[i + 1] & 0xF) << 2) | ((int) (string[i + 2] & 0xC0) >> 6)];
        *p++ = basis_64[string[i + 2] & 0x3F];
    }

    if (i < len)
    {
        *p++ = basis_64[(string[i] >> 2) & 0x3F];

        if (i == (len - 1))
        {
            *p++ = basis_64[((string[i] & 0x3) << 4)];
            *p++ = '=';
        }
        else
        {
            *p++ = basis_64[((string[i] & 0x3) << 4) | ((int) (string[i + 1] & 0xF0) >> 4)];
            *p++ = basis_64[((string[i + 1] & 0xF) << 2)];
        }

        *p++ = '=';
    }

    *p++ = '\0';

    return p - encoded;
}


int base64decode_len( const char * bufcoded )
{
    int nbytesdecoded;
    register const unsigned char *bufin;
    register int nprbytes;

    bufin = (const unsigned char *) bufcoded;

    while (pr2six[*(bufin++)] <= 63);

    nprbytes = (bufin - (const unsigned char *) bufcoded) - 1;
    nbytesdecoded = ((nprbytes + 3) / 4) * 3;

    return nbytesdecoded + 1;
}


int base64decode( char * bufplain, const char * bufcoded )
{
    int len;
    len = base64decode_binary((unsigned char *) bufplain, bufcoded);
    return len;
}


int base64encode_len( int len )
{
    return ((len + 2) / 3 * 4) + 1;
}


int base64encode( char * encoded, const char * string, int len )
{
    return base64encode_binary(encoded, (const unsigned char *) string, len);
}

/* fim-de-arquivo */
```